# Getting a N-element vector of values evenly spaced from -X to X

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

In Matlab, one can do

```
N=1024;
X=1;
dx=2*X/(N-1);
x=-X:dx:X;
```

and one has an array `x` including `-1` and `1` as endpoints.

The equivalent in numpy:

```
from numpy import r_
N=1024
X=1
dx=2*X/N
x=r_[-X:X:dx]
```

gives me `0.998046875` as `x[N-1]`, which is not right. Using `N-1` as above gives me an `N-1`-element array, which is definitely not what I want, and also does not end in `1`. I have verified that `x.dtype` is `float64`, which is the same as Matlab's representation.

How can I get a fully symmetric array in numpy as I used to have in Matlab?

Comment: How is this different from `linspace(-1, 1, 1024)`, which works in both?

Comment: @larsmans good question. I see no reason for them to be different, but they are (at least with numpy). I'm more used to not using `linspace`, to each his own I guess.

Comment: If N is your input, `linspace` is the "correct" function to use.  ("correct" is in quotes, because really, you can do whatever you want, but this is exactly what `linspace` is for.)

Comment: When `step` is a floating point number, `r_[start:stop:step]` is equivalent to `numpy.arange(start, stop, step)`.  `arange` is like a floating point version of `range`--it does not include the end point.  Because of normal floating point imprecision, this can cause surprises when the end point is computed, so I generally stick to `linspace`.

Comment: (Sorry for the comment spam.)  If you *really* want the compact notation provided by `r_`, you can use the hackish `r_[-X:X:N*1j]`, because when `step` is pure imaginary, `r_[start:stop:step]` is equivalent to `linspace(start, stop, step.real)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python code you gave is not equivalent because of the division by `N` rather than `N-1`:

```
octave:1> N=1024;
octave:2> X=1;
octave:3> dx=2*X/(N-1);
octave:4> dx
dx =  0.0019550
```

vs.

```
>>> N = 1024
>>> X = 1
>>> dx = 2. * X / N
>>> dx
0.001953125
```

So it's no surprise you get different answers. Now, to get the same result as you get in Matlab, you *can* do

```
>>> dx = 2. * X / (N - 1)
>>> x = r_[-X:X+dx:dx]
>>> x
array([-1.        , -0.99804497, -0.99608993, ...,  0.99608993,
        0.99804497,  1.        ])
>>> x.shape
(1024,)
```

But really, use `linspace`, this is what it's for and it's much more readable for someone else looking at your code.

Comment: The key being the `+dx` in `r_[-X:X+dx:dx]`. I'll see if I can convince myself to use `linspace` though `:-)`.

Comment: Be careful with `r_[start:stop+dx:dx]`. Numerical imprecision can lead to surprises.  For example, `r_[2.1:4.2+0.15:0.15]` includes `4.35` in the result.